# May I know how this integral was evaluated by using the theory of elliptic integrals?

Tags: integration, hypergeometric-function, elliptic-functions, elliptic-integrals

I can not solve the following integral using the theory of elliptic integrals:

$$\int_a^b \frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{c-\sin(x)}}dx$$

Where $a\geq 0, b>0, c>0$.

Wolfram$|$Alpha showed the following result:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%5B%2F%2Fmath:sinx%2F(a-sinx)%5E(1%2F2)%2F%2F%5D+dx

But I do not understand how Wolfra$|$Alpha came to this result.

Thanks in advance.

P.S:

How can they have also resulted in the form of hypergeometric functions ?

Comment: You can change the variable so sine becomes cosine, then use the double angle formula to get sine squared in the root

Comment: I don't know how much of a help thus is going to be but $\int_{0}^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}}=\sqrt{2}F(\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}},\frac{\pi}{2})$ You can do thus by putting $x=\frac{\pi}{2}-y$ then $\cos(y)=\cos^2(\phi)$

Comment: What are $a,b,c$ really? Can they be any number or do you have specific values in mind?

Comment: a>=0 ; b>0; c>0

Comment: Try integrating $ \int dx/\sqrt { 1+ x^4} $ It will involve $ E, F $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will show the relation to the elliptic integrals, as I said in a comment (and Albas in the next comment):

$$\sin(x)=-\sin(-x)=-\cos \left(x +\frac{\pi}{2} \right)=-1+2 \sin^2 \left( \frac{x}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4} \right)$$

$$\phi=\frac{x}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}$$

$$x=2\phi-\frac{\pi}{2}$$

$$\alpha=\frac{a}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}$$

$$\beta=\frac{b}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}$$

$$\gamma=\sqrt{\frac{2}{c+1}}$$

---

$$\int_a^b \frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{c-\sin(x)}}dx=\sqrt{2} \gamma \int_\alpha^\beta \frac{-1+2 \sin^2 \phi}{\sqrt{1-\gamma^2 \sin^2 \phi}}d\phi=$$

$$=2\sqrt{2} \gamma \int_\alpha^\beta \frac{\sin^2 \phi ~d\phi}{\sqrt{1-\gamma^2 \sin^2 \phi}}-\sqrt{2} \gamma \int_\alpha^\beta \frac{d\phi}{\sqrt{1-\gamma^2 \sin^2 \phi}}$$

---

The second integral is incomplete [elliptic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) of the first kind $F(\alpha, \gamma)-F(\beta, \gamma)$ and the second can be calculated in terms of incomplete elliptic integrals of first and second kind.

---

I will show the full solution for the easiest case of complete elliptic integrals.

$$\alpha=0$$

$$\beta=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

This means that:

$$a=-\frac{\pi}{2}$$

$$b=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Now the second integral will just be:

$$ \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{d\phi}{\sqrt{1-\gamma^2 \sin^2 \phi}}=K(\gamma)$$

On the other hand, the complete elliptic integral of the second kind is defined:

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sqrt{1-\gamma^2 \sin^2 \phi} ~~d\phi=E(\gamma)$$

$$\frac{d E}{d \gamma}=-\gamma \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin^2 \phi ~d\phi}{\sqrt{1-\gamma^2 \sin^2 \phi}}=\frac{1}{\gamma}(E(\gamma)-K(\gamma))$$

So the first integral is:

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin^2 \phi ~d\phi}{\sqrt{1-\gamma^2 \sin^2 \phi}}=\frac{1}{\gamma^2}(K(\gamma)-E(\gamma))$$

Comment: Why the denominator is;  $$sqrt( 1-((\gamma)^2)(sin\phi)^2)$$     ???

Comment: $$sqrt( c-sinx)=sqrt(c-(1-2(sin(\phi))^2))=sqrt(c-1+2(sin(\phi))^2))=sqrt(1+\gamma (sin(\phi))^2$$

Comment: Ok, thank you very very much !

Comment: How do I evaluate the first elliptic integral for generic extreme > = 0 ???

Comment: ok I will. If I find a solution to add it here . Thank you !

Comment: Unfortunately I can not find any source you cite a quell'integrale solution. Even Wolfram Alpha can solve it    
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%5B%2F%2Fmath:(sinx)%5E2%2F(1-a(sinx)%5E2)%5E(1%2F2)%2F%2F%5D+dx     
And since the initial full it could solve think it's wrong replacement made ​​, and then it will exist another more ' convenient such that the result is http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%5B%2F%2Fmath:sinx%2F(a-sinx)%5E(1%2F2)%2F%2F%5D+dx

Comment: You have an excuse why I'm wrong , thanks again ! Now I just have to figure out how to get to that result

Comment: I followed your same reasoning and I understand how it solves the integral. Thanks again for your help was very valuable .